# For loop through model in migration not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this migration that is to edit all the pre existing profiles. The migration is not working.

```
class FixProfilesForNewFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    Profile.all do |p|
      p.public = true
      p.email_settings = "normal"
      p.save
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: use `p.save!` so it throws exception if there is a validation error

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class FixProfilesForNewFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    Profile.all do |p|
      p.public = true
      p.email_settings = "normal"
      p.send
      p.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

1. try using `def self.up` instead of `def change` (and off course the equivalent `def self.down`)
2. If you have structure change instruction before your query, you need to call `Profile.reset_column_information` before your query

Result:

```
class FixProfilesForNewFields < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    # change_column, add_column, etc ...

    Profile.reset_column_information

    Profile.all do |p|
      p.public = true
      p.email_settings = "normal"
      p.save
    end
  end

  def self.down
    # remove_column, change_columns, etc...
  end
end
```

And if you still have a problem, you should run rake with backtrace option and paste the error stack in your question `rake db:migrate --backtrace`